# Create vertical image carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm trying to create a *custom vertical image carousel* because I can't use any plugins out there due to the js events attached to the images which I need to retain and the only way that would work for me is to create custom carousel.

**Functionalities**

- Image carousel does have 3 equal sizes in the viewport.
- Image carousel does have next/previous button which allow you to view/select more images.
- The next/previous button allows only one step at a time, meaning it will not select the next set of images and display it in the viewport.

[image]

- Carousel offers you to select any images in the viewport and this will sync when the next/prev button is clicked

[image]

All functionalities listed above is implemented already.

**PROBLEM**

The last image will not snap/stop before the next button, as it will create blank space in between.

[image][image]

**JS Code**

```
$(function(){
        var image_height = 0;
        var gallery_offset = 0;
        var image_count = $('img.thumbnail').length;
        var click_count = 0;
        var image_height = 0;
        var last_images_count = 0;

        $('.gallery-container a').click(function(){
          $('.gallery-container a').removeClass('active')
            $(this).addClass('active');

        });

        jQuery('.thumbnail').each(function(){
          $(this).on('load', function(){ image_height = $(this).parent().outerHeight(); });
          image_height = $(this).parent().outerHeight();
        })

        // Disable arrows if the images count is 3 below
        if(image_count <= 3) {
            $('.product-more-pictures .up, .product-more-pictures .down').addClass('disabled')
            click_count = 0;
        }

        // Set the first image as active
        jQuery('.gallery-container img.thumbnail').first().click();
        var thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');

        $('.gallery-container a').on('click', function() {
            thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');
        });

        $('.product-more-pictures .down').on('click', function (e) {
            $('.product-more-pictures .up').removeClass('disabled')
            if(thumb_active.nextAll(':lt(1)').length) {
              thumb_active.nextAll(':lt(1)').children().click()
              thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');

            } 

            if( ! thumb_active.next().length) {
              $(this).addClass('disabled')
            } else {
              $(this).removeClass('disabled');
            }

            if (click_count < image_count) {
                click_count = click_count + 1;

                update_gallery('down');
            }



        });

        $('.product-more-pictures .up').on('click', function () {
            $('.product-more-pictures .down').removeClass('disabled')
            if(thumb_active.prevAll(':lt(1)').length) {
              thumb_active.prevAll(':lt(1)').children().click()
              thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');
            }

            if( ! thumb_active.prev().length) {
              $(this).addClass('disabled')
            } else {
              $(this).removeClass('disabled');
            }

            if (click_count > 0) {
                click_count = click_count - 1;

                update_gallery('up');

            }
        });

        function update_gallery(direction) {         
            gallery_offset = click_count * image_height;
            last_images_count = thumb_active.nextAll().length;

            $(".gallery-container").animate({
              'top': '-' + gallery_offset + 'px'
            }, 800);

        }

});
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qrvrdjch/6/

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...
you need to initialize the click count as -1, and change the if (click_count < image_count)  to this "if (click_count < image_count - 3)" since on load default selected image is first, so this one will serve your need I guess
NB: no change required in css and HTML

```
$(function(){
    var image_height = 0;
    var gallery_offset = 0;
    var image_count = $('img.thumbnail').length;
    var click_count = -1;
    var image_height = 0;
    var last_images_count = 0;

    $('.gallery-container a').click(function(){
      $('.gallery-container a').removeClass('active')
        $(this).addClass('active');

    });

    jQuery('.thumbnail').each(function(){
      $(this).on('load', function(){ image_height = $(this).parent().outerHeight(); });
      image_height = $(this).parent().outerHeight();
    })

    // Disable arrows if the images count is 3 below
    if(image_count <= 3) {
        $('.product-more-pictures .up, .product-more-pictures .down').addClass('disabled')
        click_count = 0;
    }

    // Set the first image as active
    jQuery('.gallery-container img.thumbnail').first().click();
    var thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');

    $('.gallery-container a').on('click', function() {
        thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');
    });

    $('.product-more-pictures .down').on('click', function (e) {
        $('.product-more-pictures .up').removeClass('disabled')
        if(thumb_active.nextAll(':lt(1)').length) {
          thumb_active.nextAll(':lt(1)').children().click()
          thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');

        } 

        if( ! thumb_active.next().length) {
          $(this).addClass('disabled')
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('disabled');
        }
        if (click_count < image_count - 3) {
            console.log(image_count)
            console.log(click_count)
            click_count = click_count + 1;

            update_gallery('down');
        }



    });

    $('.product-more-pictures .up').on('click', function () {
        $('.product-more-pictures .down').removeClass('disabled')
        if(thumb_active.prevAll(':lt(1)').length) {
          thumb_active.prevAll(':lt(1)').children().click()
          thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');
        }

        if( ! thumb_active.prev().length) {
          $(this).addClass('disabled')
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('disabled');
        }

        if (click_count > 0) {
            click_count = click_count - 1;

            update_gallery('up');

        }
    });

    function update_gallery(direction) {         
        gallery_offset = click_count * image_height;
        last_images_count = thumb_active.nextAll().length;

        $(".gallery-container").animate({
          'top': '-' + gallery_offset + 'px'
        }, 800);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there. You just need to edit one condition.
Change "if (click_count < image_count)" under click event of down button(line 48 in JSFiddle) to "if (click_count < image_count-3)"

```js
$(function(){
        var image_height = 0;
        var gallery_offset = 0;
        var image_count = $('img.thumbnail').length;
        var click_count = 0;
       var image_height = 0;
        var last_images_count = 0;
        
        $('.gallery-container a').click(function(){
          $('.gallery-container a').removeClass('active')
         $(this).addClass('active');
          
        });
        
       jQuery('.thumbnail').each(function(){
          $(this).on('load', function(){ image_height = $(this).parent().outerHeight(); });
          image_height = $(this).parent().outerHeight();
        })
        
        // Disable arrows if the images count is 3 below
        if(image_count <= 3) {
         $('.product-more-pictures .up, .product-more-pictures .down').addClass('disabled')
            click_count = 0;
        }
        
        // Set the first image as active
        jQuery('.gallery-container img.thumbnail').first().click();
       var thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');
        
        $('.gallery-container a').on('click', function() {
         thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');
        });

        $('.product-more-pictures .down').on('click', function (e) {
           $('.product-more-pictures .up').removeClass('disabled')
           if(thumb_active.nextAll(':lt(1)').length) {
              thumb_active.nextAll(':lt(1)').children().click()
              thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');

            } 
          
            if( ! thumb_active.next().length) {
              $(this).addClass('disabled')
            } else {
              $(this).removeClass('disabled');
            }
            
            if (click_count < image_count-3) {
                click_count = click_count + 1;
              
                update_gallery('down');
            }
          
            
           
        });

        $('.product-more-pictures .up').on('click', function () {
           $('.product-more-pictures .down').removeClass('disabled')
           if(thumb_active.prevAll(':lt(1)').length) {
              thumb_active.prevAll(':lt(1)').children().click()
              thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');
            }
          
           if( ! thumb_active.prev().length) {
              $(this).addClass('disabled')
            } else {
              $(this).removeClass('disabled');
            }
            
            if (click_count > 0) {
                click_count = click_count - 1;
                
                update_gallery('up');
                
            }
        });
      
        function update_gallery(direction) {         
            gallery_offset = click_count * image_height;
            last_images_count = thumb_active.nextAll().length;
           
            $(".gallery-container").animate({
              'top': '-' + gallery_offset + 'px'
            }, 800);
        
        }
        
});
```

```css
.product-more-pictures a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-more-pictures a.disabled {
  pointer-events: none !important;
  cursor: default;
  visibility: visible !important;
  background: #C3C3C3;
}

.product-more-pictures a.down.disabled:before,
.product-more-pictures a.up.disabled:before{
 content: ' ';
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.42);
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.product-more-pictures {
  text-align: right;
  height: 549px;
  width: 111px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;

}

.gallery-container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

.gallery-container img {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#product-photos .product-more-pictures {
  width: 18.516667%;
}

.product-more-pictures .up,
.product-more-pictures .down {
  position: absolute;
  background: #999;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 80;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.product-more-pictures .up { top: 0px; }
.product-more-pictures .down {
  bottom: 0px; 
}

.product-more-pictures a.active img {
  border: solid 1px rgba(95, 95, 95,0.75) !important;
}

.product-more-pictures .icon-chevron-up,
.product-more-pictures .icon-chevron-down {
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 21px;
  position: relative;
}

.product-more-pictures .icon-chevron-up {
  top: 0px;
}

.zoomContainer { z-index: 999; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-more-pictures desktop-3">
      <a href="#" class="up">up</a>
      <div class="gallery-container">
      
          <a href="#">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Name_it_to_Win_It_11-27_027_compact.jpg?v=1451925772" alt="Sheer Perfection Tunic">
          </a>
    
          <a href="#">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Name_it_to_Win_It_11-27_111_compact.jpg?v=1451925773"alt="Sheer Perfection Tunic">
          </a>
      
          <a href="#">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Name_it_to_Win_It_11-27_194_compact.jpg?v=1451925774" alt="Sheer Perfection Tunic">
          </a>
    
          <a href="#" >
            <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Name_it_to_Win_It_11-27_029_compact.jpg?v=1451925774" alt="Sheer Perfection Tunic">
          </a>
    
          <a href="#">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Name_it_to_Win_It_11-27_095_compact.jpg?v=1451925775" data-image-id="8200864135" alt="Sheer Perfection Tunic">
          </a>
    
          <a href="#">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Name_it_to_Win_It_11-27_135_compact.jpg?v=1451925776" data-image-id="8200864327" alt="Sheer Perfection Tunic">
          </a>
    
          <a href="#" >
            <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Name_it_to_Win_It_11-27_149_compact.jpg?v=1451925776" data-image-id="8200864775" alt="Sheer Perfection Tunic">
          </a>
    
          <a href="#" >
            <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Name_it_to_Win_It_11-27_152_compact.jpg?v=1451925777" data-image-id="8200865671" alt="Sheer Perfection Tunic">
          </a>
    
          <a href="#">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0190/3782/products/Name_it_to_Win_It_11-27_159_compact.jpg?v=1451925778" data-image-id="8200866183" alt="Sheer Perfection Tunic">
          </a>
      
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="down">down</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
        var image_height = 0;
        var gallery_offset = 0;
        var image_count = $('img.thumbnail').length;
        var image_show = 3;
        var click_count = 0;
       var image_height = 0;
        var last_images_count = 0;
        
        $('.gallery-container a').click(function(){
          $('.gallery-container a').removeClass('active')
         $(this).addClass('active');
          
        });
        
       jQuery('.thumbnail').each(function(){
          $(this).on('load', function(){ image_height = $(this).parent().outerHeight(); });
          image_height = $(this).parent().outerHeight();
        })
        
        // Disable arrows if the images count is 3 below
        if(image_count <= 3) {
         $('.product-more-pictures .up, .product-more-pictures .down').addClass('disabled')
            click_count = 0;
        }
        
        // Set the first image as active
        jQuery('.gallery-container img.thumbnail').first().click();
       var thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');
        
        $('.gallery-container a').on('click', function() {
         thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');
        });

        $('.product-more-pictures .down').on('click', function (e) {
           $('.product-more-pictures .up').removeClass('disabled')
           if(thumb_active.nextAll(':lt(1)').length) {
              thumb_active.nextAll(':lt(1)').children().click()
              thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');

            } 
          
            if( ! thumb_active.next().length || click_count > (image_count-image_show)) {
              $(this).addClass('disabled')
            } else {
              $(this).removeClass('disabled');
            }
          
            if (click_count < (image_count-image_show)) {
                click_count = click_count+1;
                update_gallery('down');
            }
          
            
           
        });

        $('.product-more-pictures .up').on('click', function () {
           $('.product-more-pictures .down').removeClass('disabled')
           if(thumb_active.prevAll(':lt(1)').length) {
              thumb_active.prevAll(':lt(1)').children().click()
              thumb_active = jQuery('.gallery-container .active');
            }
          
           if( ! thumb_active.prev().length) {
              $(this).addClass('disabled')
            } else {
              $(this).removeClass('disabled');
            }
            
            if (click_count > 0) {
                click_count = click_count - 1;
                
                update_gallery('up');
                
            }
        });
      
        function update_gallery(direction) {  
            gallery_offset = click_count * image_height;
            last_images_count = thumb_active.nextAll().length;
           
            $(".gallery-container").animate({
              'top': '-' + gallery_offset + 'px'
            }, 800);
        
        }
        
});
```

Hi,

I have added one more veriable image_show=3 for handle image count.